# Child component returns props as null

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am fetching data from api in the parent and I'm sending the data as a prop to the child component. When I try consoling the props it returns null. Dont know why. But the props are getting displayed when the child component is rendered again

This is parent component

```
componentWillMount(){
        fetch('http://13.234.252.37:5000/api/user_information/'+ this.props.propUser_id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({fileUploadedData: data.Documents, dashboardPiscore: data.piscore}, () => {
                console.log("set sytate", this.state.fileUploadedData);
            })
        })
    }

return(
this.state.dashboardHome ? <DashboardHome analysisData={this.state.fileUploadedData} /> : null 
)
```

This is the child component

```
class dashboardHome extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log("props in cons", this.props);
    this.state= {
      annualIncome: '0',
      monthlyExpense: '0',
      monthlySavings: '0',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("props in home", this.props);
    if(this.props.analysisData !== null) 
    {
      this.setState({
      annualIncome: this.props.analysisData[0].Salary,
      monthlyExpense: this.props.analysisData[1].average_monthly_expense,
      monthlySavings: this.props.analysisData[1].average_monthly_savings
      })
 render(){  
return(
<div>//dashboard</div>
)
}
```

For the first time when component renders the props is consoled as null. When I render it again the props value are set. Please help me out with a way to set the props at the first rendering of the component.
 The props are null now. When I click on some other tab of dashboard and come back again to the dashboard the props are set properly as expected
[image: this is the screenshot check the console.]

Comment: Why do you use fetch in componentWillMount ? The correct method should be componentDidMount

Comment: Even if I use it in DidMount it didn't work properly. I just tried that out.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is advised to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`. Also, you said yourself you are fetching data from Api. Before the data is fetched and stored in state, of course the initial props passed to the child will be empty. If that causes issues, you may consider using some default values, before the real data arrives. Or you can also not render the child component at all before the data arrives, and show loading indicator.

Comment: No default values will not work properly because this application demands user entered data to appear on the dashboard(like graphs kind of representation). Will setting a default value work out in this case.

Comment: Kindly suggest me a better way to assign the data I get from the API to the props

Comment: @HareiniSreethi Show a loading indicator or something before data arrives

Comment: Ok i'll try using a loading component. Can I know when will my child receive the props from its parent

Comment: @HareiniSreethi When parent writes `<Child para={x}/>` child *always* receives this props, regardless if `x`'s value is undefined or not.

Comment: @HareiniSreethi Did  you think *why* is it problem if initially you receive nulls in Child?

Comment: Actually my api returns values like annual income, expense etc, I am passing these values to the child and I want them to be rendered as soon as the user logs in. Thats why I don't want my props to be set to null initially

Comment: @HareiniSreethi Yes but I asked what is the problem if they are passed as null initially? does it cause a problem?

Comment: Yes ofcourse it does cause a problem. There is no value displayed on the dashboard (as you can see in the image), but actually there are  values coming from the api. Those data are getting displayed if I click on some other tab eg. Piscore and click back again on dashboard

Comment: Ok i'll try that out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a short circuit to your conditional?

```
this.state.dashboardHome && this.state.dashboardHome ?
```

So it would ignore it the first time because it would evaluate to false initially, then on the second render, it will see the data, resolve to true then run the rest of the ternary statement. That way you will not receive an error. I have this problem when using Hooks and it usually fixes it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html 
Inline If with Logical && Operator section